# Probability distribution question?

Tags: probability

The question asks for the expected value E[X] and the variance V[X] of the following:

Let a and b be integers such that a < b. Let X be a uniformly distributed random
interval on the integers from a to b, so X has the following distributin:

X = {i , a<= i <= b with probability (1/(b-a+i))}
X = {0 otherwise}

My attempted solution:

E[X] = $\frac{i}{(b-a+i)}$

V[X] = $\frac{i^2}{b-a+i} - \frac{i^2}{(b-a+i)^2}$

I was wondering if this was correct or is there something I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you think there should be *sums* somewhere?

Comment: @Did thank you for your hint, I was lost on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively the mean has to be the midpoint of $a$ and $b$.

Meanwhile $i$ should not be an unbound variable.

So you can have the mean as $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=a}^{b} \dfrac{i}{b-a+1} = \dfrac{a+b}{2}$$

and the variance as $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=a}^{b} \dfrac{\left(i-\sum_{j=a}^{b} \frac{j}{b-a+1}\right)^2}{b-a+1} =\displaystyle\sum_{i=a}^{b} \dfrac{i^2}{b-a+1} -\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=a}^{b} \dfrac{i}{b-a+1}\right)^2= \dfrac{(b-a+1)^2 -1}{12}.$$

See Wikipedia on the [discrete uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29).

Comment: Thank you I thought my answer was too simple, I appreciate it!